# Duplicate items in windows 8 taskbar

Tags: windows-8, taskbar, duplicate

Ok so, I've done the stupid thing of deleting my desktop folder so I could symlink it somewhere else. That caused a lot of issues and one of them is that the items in the taskbar have duplicates (or at least that's what it seems to be).
Here is an example:

[image: Here is an example]

Notice the `(2)` next to `Google Chrome`, I have the same thing happening to SublimeText and PowerShell. I thought that maybe If I could find the registry or the folder they I could remove the duplicates but I didn't manage to find it. That's why I'm asking for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, nevermind.
I just found the location of that directory, it's located at `%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`. Deleting the non (2) versions of the entries fixed it (and then removing the (2) labels).